# Next.js how to getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

for context I am in a folder in pages in a file named [id].jsx. How do I get getServerSide props to return the name of the page ex /page/id123 I want it to return id123.

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from "react";

export default function Global() {
        console.log(context)
        const address = useAddress();
        const disconnectWallet = useDisconnect();

        while (address) {
            return (
                <Link href="/">
                <a className="absolute pt-1 text-xl font-semibold transform -translate-x-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2"> Click Here To Login</a>
                </Link>
            </>
        );
      }

export function getServerSideProps(context) {
    console.log("context: ", context.params)
    return {
        props: {context},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your dynamic page is called `[id].jsx`, you can access that `id` in your `getServerSideProps` with: `context.params.id`.

```
export function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {id: context.params.id},
    }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
export default function Global({ id }) {
   console.log(id);
    ...

}
```

You can also access it using `router` object that comes from Next.js' `useRouter` hook:

```
export default function Global() {
   const router = useRouter();
   const { id } = router.query;
   console.log(id);
    ...

}
```

Comment: @tyler I think you should use @ivanatias' third code example, ```getServerSideProps ``` is used to make SSR, by not using this method in your page you are only generating a static HTML file which is way more efficient than SSR only to get what you could do with only the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctx.resolvedUrl`. It will either return what you want or you'll be able parse the needed part out